# Symfony2 and RememberMe token exception

Tags: symfony, remember-me

We are building an application using Symfony2 framework.

There is a custom authentication manager implemented which works fine, except when a user connects and select the 'Remember me' token. The user is logged in, can navigate throw the website, and after a moment, which is random in a range from about 5 minutes to about 1 hour (maybe more), the following exception occurs:

```
The UserProviderInterface implementation must return an instance of UserInterface, but returned "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\TokenBasedRememberMeServices".
```

The only solution to 'fix' this (and access the website again) at this point is to remove the rememberme token from the browser.

I couldn't really find any suggestions for this issue already, so I thought I might ask here in case anyone had already encountered the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your user provider should either return an instance of `\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface` or throw `\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException` in case it fails to find a user. Nothing else.

In my case it looks like this:

```
public function loadUserByUsername($loginOrEmail)
{
    $qb = $this->dm
        ->getRepository('MyBundle:User')
        ->createQueryBuilder('u');

    $qb->where()->orX()
        ->eq()->localName('u')->literal($loginOrEmail)->end()
        ->eq()->field('u.email')->literal($loginOrEmail);

    $user = $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();

    if (!$user) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('User "%s" not found.', $loginOrEmail));
    }

    return $user;
}
```

This approach will solve all the issues.
Look closely at `\Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\EntityUserProvider`

Hope it helped a bit :)